# "npm ERR! Linux 4.19.43-coreos" - NPM Error

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a project developed with Laravel, using git for version control. My repo is hosted by Bitbucket.  I set up autodeploy to a remote environment upon merge, using a .yml file.  Everything was working great until yesterday.

It looks like there was an issue with npm yesterday morning (https://status.npmjs.org/) that has since been resolved.  However, ever since the incident, my autodeploy has been failing due to the following error: *npm ERR! Linux 4.19.43-coreos*

Here ismy .yml file:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
            - node
          script:
            # Build Laravel
            - "composer install"
            - "cp .env.test.example .env"
            - "cp .env.prod.php .env.php"
            - "php artisan key:generate"
            # Build database
            - "touch storage/database.sqlite"
            # Build client assets
            - "npm install"
            - gulp
```

Here is the log right before failure:

```
+ npm install
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.16.0
.
.
.
[lots of packages successfully installed]
.
.
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inputmask
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 5:16:09 PM
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 5:16:09 PM
npm http fetch GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inputmask/-/inputmask-3.3.11.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inputmask/-/inputmask-3.3.11.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 4.19.43-coreos
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.16.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
```

Any ideas on what's happening here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a node package, admin-lte.  This package had inputmask as a dependency, and that was failing.